# Sentry: Can I refer to a previously sent event?

Tags: sentry

When I have sent a custom [Sentry event](https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/integrate-backend/capturing-errors/),

- Can I update it later ?
- Or can I refer to it in a new event, so that the Sentry Dashboard knows they are related ?

E.g. if the server **doesn't** respond for a long time, I want to send an event to be aware of potential problems. Obviously I can't send an event if the server doesn't responde *ever*.

But if the server **does** respond finally, I would like to kind of *update* that previous event to something like *"This still took too long, but at least the server did respond after 27 seconds (and the user didn't go away)"*.

E.g.:

First event should be something like:

```
sendSentryEvent({
    eventId: 'c0e3e4fa-df19-43a5-825a-6c4da1362c56',
    message: 'no server response for 15 seconds'
});
```

Second event should be something like:

```
sendSentryEvent({
    eventId: '(actually dont need an event id in other cases)',
    relatedId: 'c0e3e4fa-df19-43a5-825a-6c4da1362c56',
    update: 'still took too long, but at least the server did respond after 27 seconds',
});
```